# Angular dropdown not being selected

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown in Angular that is not selected. I already added the value to the ng-model the particular address of the json_array selected however, it is not being set in the dropdown.

Here is my object.

> 0: { Id:1 LocationId:1 Name:"John Doe" } 1 { Id: 2 Name: "Jane
>   Doe"}

In which I managed to make a dropdown using

```
  <select 
      class="form-control"
      ng-model="Approver"
      ng-options="approver.Name as approver.Name for approver in approverList">
     </select>
```

And in my Angular controller

```
$scope.Approver = $scope.approverList[1];
```

In which Jane Doe is not being selected.

What is the cause of this. Thanks!

Comment: You need to either change ng-options with approver as approver.Name or in your angular controller, set $scope.approver = $scope.approverList[1].Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is not correct, try this.

```
<select 
  class="form-control"
  ng-model="Approver"
  ng-options="approver as approver.Name for approver in approverList track by approver.Id">
 </select>
```

[Read here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) from angular team for more information.